# To add shareable link on apps without login func

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, google-sheets-api

I have a project to make English learning apps.

There is four layer of users; headquarters, admins, classes and students. For better UX, I want to add shareable links to students my page. So no need for login func. to students. Students can use app without login.

Gem called forward is similar to this func. Is there another way to implement this func.?

Gem called forward is the best solution...?
https://rubygems.org/gems/forward

Comment: Forward isn't what you're looking for - it merely exposes localhost

Comment: Oh I was thinking it too difficult. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rails views require no login by default. To get a link that doesn't require users to log in you simply do not add a feature that requires login. You can then in the view check if there is a user signed in and add extra buttons for admin features.

Comment: Oh I was thinking it too difficult. Thank you!